# Using Trezor, trying to retrieve tx_key

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-key

I made sure to check that store-tx-info = 1 before sending.

I seem to recall trying this in an earlier version and it was successful

Now I am getting a result of:

get_tx_key txid

Wallet password:

Tx key: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Monero v0.14.1.0, 
Trezor v2.1.0

Is there any way I can still recover it from the wallet file?

Answer (score 0):

Some [fixes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/5211) were merged to the master branch recently, so should make the next release (any day now™).

Comment: This was running the version from tthe master branch at the time.

Comment: Well in that case, shouldn't you be opening a GitHub issue instead, so the developers who believe they have fixed this issue can look into it?